# Can only use wildcard queries on keyword, text and wildcard fields - not on [id] which is of type [long]

Tags: elasticsearch

POST'ing data to an index:

```
GET test/_mapping
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/101
{
  "id":101,
  "name":"hello"
}

POST test/_doc/102
{
  "id":102,
  "name":"hi"
}
```

Running a wildcard search pattern:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*101* *hello*",
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "fields": [
        "id",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Error is:**

> "reason" : "Can only use wildcard queries on keyword, text and wildcard fields - not on [id] which is of type [long]",

My code was working fine in version 7.6.0, but I get the error in Elasticsearch version 7.13.1.  What changed between these versions and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible to perform wildcards on numeric data types. It is better to convert those integers to strings.

You need to modify your index mapping to

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to perform a partial search you can use [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Comment: @Sanjit Vimal did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ESCoder... I understand the concept and i can achieve it in multiple ways,  but what is the change from 7.6.0 to 7.13.1?